# Column heads of a pandas dataframe not being recognized?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, keyerror

I have 3 pd dataframes, and for some reason only 2 of them have this issue, although all 3 of them were created the same way.
I imported them with:

```
  df1= pd.read_csv('filepath.csv')
  df2 = pd.read_csv('filepath2.csv')
  df3 = pd.read_csv('filepath3.csv')
```

the code calling the columns of the dataframes looks like this:

```
features = df2['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6']
target = df2['t']
x = df2[features]
y = df2[target]
```

and while this worked for the first dataframe, for df2 and df3 it does not. I get a key error when the code is run:

```
KeyError: ('f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6')
```

while df2.keys() returns this:

```
Index(['f0', 'f1', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6',
       'f7', 't'],
      dtype='object')
```

and

```
print(dfPNC.columns.tolist())
```

returns this:

```
['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 't']
```

I have tried fixing it with these methods, however have had no success:

```
sep=r'\s*,\s*' #when reading the csv

sep = r',', skipinitialspace = True, engine = 'python' #2nd attempt when reading the csv

features = [['f1','f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5',
   'f6', 'f7']] #3rd attempt however raises a boolean error
```

Comment: Looks like your file doesn't contain a column called `t`?

Comment: it does, I just edited it to reflect that, sorry
when I try to run the target column first, I am met with KeyError: "None of [Int64Index...dtype='int64', length=153)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Why not just `x = df2[['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6']]` and `y = df2['t']` (or `y = df[['t']]` if you want a dataframe...) ?

Comment: it raises the same errors, I'm not trying to create a new dataframe, I'm trying to assign these x and y variables to the features and target values of the dataframe so that I can perform analytical functions

Comment: To extract by columns, you need `[[` like `features = df2[['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6']]`.